# setting up a local database to be updated from a master database

Tags: php, sql, database, synchronization

I'm looking for an efficient way to keep multiple databases (on different servers) sync with a `master` database (also on a different server). Mind you I only need a one way sync (from master to all others).

As I was searching I came across multiple solutions.

- `replication` : Which (from what I read) is unreliable, because if the slave servers or down temporarily or anything like that, they end up missing information. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)
- `Injection`   : Which I also think is unreliable, not to mention a security problem because you're directly communicating with the slave databases.

Since I didn't like what I saw, I decided to make my own system (ultimately not liking it either) My system was to make a new table called `ORDERS` , and would basically hold values that could be translated as "Delete item with id 32 in table someTable" and on the slave side they would follow each of these instructions.

What do you think is the best way? The database is really small (with at most 3000 entries), so I want a really simple solution. Thanks

Comment: It's *possible* [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) might work for you in place of a disk-based database clone.

Comment: if both servers are on unix then you can dump the database to file `mysqldump -u USER -p PASSWORD DATABASE > filename.sql ` then use file_get_contents or curl to retrieve the file then use `mysqldump -u USER -p PASSWORD DATABASE < filename.sql ` to load it OR pipe it directly across with a shell: `mysqldump --opt --compress --user=USERHERE --password=PWHERE
--host=SOURCE.HOST.HERE SOURCE_DB_NAME | mysql --user=USERHERE
--password=PWHERE --host=TARGET.HOST.HERE -D TARGET_DB_NAME -C
TARGET_DB_NAME`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that's kinda my last resort (given how inefficient that is) Thank's though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I feel the same about your solution too :s

Comment: I think you should try your question either at [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thank's @JaredFarrish I posted it in both, hopefully someone answers it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mysql, just use a master/slave setup. Not sure where you heard it's unreliable if the slave goes down. One of the settings is how long of a replication log history to keep. If this is set to 7 days on the master, then a slave can go down and be offline for up to 7 days. When the slave starts back up, it starts reading from the replication log where it left off. It will take a while to catch up, but you won't lose anything.

Companies have been using mysql replication for years with no problems. I have a master-master circular replication setup with slave off of each master. I've actually had a triple master setup during a migration with the servers on opposite side of the country.

Comment: is there a way I can be notified on the slave server that it's being updated? Because the tables sometimes reference images which are only available on the master server

Comment: just to clarify @BrentBaisley , on my master table I would have tables that will have values like "image.png" is there a way that the server can run a php script on replication, that way the slave can also download the referenced images? Thank's for everything

Comment: the database likely doesn't use images from the file system, it also stores a reference to them. Your web server is what "loads" the images. If you need to have images present on both server, then I would use something like NFS. As an aside, the site I manage is bigstockphoto.com, which is all about images.